# UILabel value is not changing based on the pickerView selection

Tags: swift, xcode, pickerview

I want to choose and display the correct dataset from Firebase, based on the pickerView selection.

The main problem - the values of the UILabels are not changing.
The second thing I would like to note, that the pickerView does not disappear after I click on one of the values in it.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var priceView: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dayView: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var monthView: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var personPicker: UITextField!
    
    var ref: DatabaseReference?
    var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
    
    var postData = [String]()
    var person : String = "jack"
    
    let people = ["jack", "jenny", "don"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let pickerView = UIPickerView()
        personPicker.delegate = self
        
        personPicker.inputView = pickerView
        
        
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        
        ref?.child("xf").child(person).child("price").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            if let i = snapshot.value as? Double 
                    self.priceView.text = "\(i)"
                    self.priceView.reloadInputViews()
                }            
        })
        
        ref?.child("xf").child(person).child("day").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            if let i = snapshot.value as? String {
                    self.dayView.text = "\(i)"
                    self.dayView.reloadInputViews()
                }            
        })
      
        ref?.child("xf").child(person).child("month").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            
            if let i = snapshot.value as? String {
                    self.monthView.text = "\(i)"
                    self.monthView.reloadInputViews()
                }           
        })
        
    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
            return people.count
        }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
            return people[row]
        }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
            personPicker.text = people[row]
            person = people[row]
        }
    
    

}
```

For the first issue, I tried adding the 'person = people[row]' but the values in the UILabes do not change

For the issue with the pickerView removal, I tried adding 'pickerView.isHidden = true', but it only removes the values, not the card

Xcode Version 12.3

Comment: The second issue was resolved with the personPicker.resignFirstResponder()

Comment: Try adding personPicker.datasource = self in viewDidLoad()